# Check what toolboxes the code used

Tags: matlab

I have written some programs and I want to check if they use specific toolboxes to ensure that they will work on other `MATLAB` installation. Is there a way to see what toolboxes does a program used? I have tried to use the profile function:

```
profile on
simulation %run program
profile off
profile viewer
```

But sorting through all the entry in the profile doesn't make it obvious to spot which toolboxes are used.

There is also the command:

```
license('inuse')
```

But this will list all the licenses I have accessed sinc I started `MATLAB` and doesn't tell me where in the code the toolbox is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excellent tool to find dependencies: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17291-fdep-a-pedestrian-function-dependencies-finder/content/fdep.m

Comment: Unfortunately the function you pointed out here no longer works for the later Matlab versions